# Does T-SQL allow multiple ELSE IF? Or must I nest conditionals? SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, conditional-statements, computer-science

In C#, you can have multiple conditionals of which only one will execute:

```
if (Condition1)
{
    // Condition1 is true.
}
else if (Condition2)
{
    // Condition1 is false and Condition2 is true.
}
else if (Condition3)
{
    // Condition1 is false and Condition2 is false and Condition3 is true.
}
else
{
    // Condition1, Condition2, and Condition3 are false.
}
```

But does the same logic work in T-SQL or must you nest the statements?  Will this execute exactly like the above code?

```
IF @variable1 = 1
    BEGIN
        --@variable1 = 1
    END
ELSE IF @variable1 = 2
    BEGIN
        --@variable1 = 2
    END
ELSE IF @variable3 = 3
    BEGIN
        --@variable1 = 3
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        --@variable1 > 3
    END
```

I might be wrong here, but isn't there a way the SQL code would not evaluate the same way as the C# code from a logic standpoint if SQL doesn't allow multiple conditionals like C#?  For example, is execution of each new ELSE IF guaranteed to be exclusive of the previous statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are the same. Only one condition will be executed and the order of conditions is crucial.

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/375597)**

```
DECLARE @variable1 INT = 2
        ,@variable3 INT = 3;

IF @variable1 = 1
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'First IF'
    END
ELSE IF @variable1 = 2
    BEGIN
         SELECT 'Second IF'
    END
ELSE IF @variable3 = 3
    BEGIN
         SELECT 'Third IF'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
         SELECT 'Else Clause'
    END
```

Comment: I guess this seems obvious now.  Not sure what I was thinking.

Comment: You are correct in that if and else may only execute one block.  By convention we put the else-ifs on the same indentation level, which makes it confusing, but in reality they're nested:  if {Block} else { if {block} else {Block}}

Answer (score 1):

In both the C# case as well as the SQL Server case, the ELSE keyword indicates that ONLY one block beneath an IF statement with a valid condition is going to be executed.  Without ELSE, that's when the behavior changes.  Your example is fine.